# How does the Mind Thrust psionic power work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

The description of the [Mind Thrust](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/mindThrust.htm) psionic power in the SRD says:

> **Level**: Psion/wilder 1
> **Display**: Auditory
> **Manifesting Time**: 1 standard action
> **Range**: Close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels)
> **Target**: One creature
> **Duration**: Instantaneous
> **Saving Throw**: Will negates
> **Power Resistance**: Yes
> **Power Points**: 1
>
> You instantly deliver a massive assault on the thought pathways of any
> one creature, dealing 1d10 points of damage to it.
>
> #### Augment
>
> For every additional power point you spend, this power’s damage
> increases by 1d10 points. For each extra 2d10 points of damage, this
> power’s save DC increases by 1.

Do I need to make any attack rolls? Or does this power just instantly trigger the enemy to make a Will save roll, and deal damage if he fails?

Answer (score 3):

## The [*mind thrust*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#mind-thrust) power doesn't require an attack roll

The typical manifester takes a standard action to manifest the 1st-level psion/wilder power [***mind thrust***](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#mind-thrust) [telepathy] (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 120) and a subject within close range to whom the manifester has both line of sight and line of effect makes a Will saving throw. Failure means that the victim is dealt 1d10 points of damage (or more if the power's augmented or otherwise modified). Success means that the victim is unaffected.

Keep in mind that "[t]he maximum number of [power] points you can spend on a power (for any reason) is equal to your manifester level" (63 and [here](http://dndsrd.net/psionicDescriptions.html#power-points)). This tends to keep the *mind thrust* power's potential damage reasonable. (And the lack of an attack roll means no scoring critical hits with the power, so there's that.)

Also remember that the power *mind thrust* possesses the [descriptor](http://dndsrd.net/psionicDescriptions.html#descriptor) mind-affecting, making it useless against, for example, a typical creature that possesses the type [construct](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#construct), [ooze](http://dndsrd.net/monstersOtoR.html#ooze), or [undead](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#undead).

Finally, the binary nature of the power (i.e. *either* the subject is dealt damage *or* the subject is unaffected) makes the power, at low levels, pretty much comparable to owning a bow except that once the power is taken, using it costs power points instead of copper pieces… and cp are usually easier for an adventurer to come by. (In a campaign I ran, the [psychic rogue](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20040723b) PC took the power *mind thrust.* Over the course of, like, four levels that took 6 real-world months of once-a-week 4-hour sessions to play, the PC used the power—I think—but once. There were just always better options.)